# Using carry flag after shift operation

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

For the div/mod part of the following code:

```
int pow(int x, unsigned int n)
{
    int y = 1;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        auto m = n%2;
        n = n/2;
        if (m)
            y *= x;
        x = x*x;
    }
    return x*y;
}
```

I'd expect assembly like

```
shr n
cmovc y, yx
```

But gcc/clang and even icc don't use the carry flag here (using 2 registers and and/test instead): [https://godbolt.org/z/L6VUZ1](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+pow(int+x,+unsigned+int+n)%0A%7B%0A%09int+y+%3D+1%3B%0A%09while+(n+%3E+1)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09auto+m+%3D+n%252%3B%0A%09%09n+%3D+n/2%3B%0A%09%09if+(m)%0A%09%09%09y+*%3D+x%3B%0A%09%09x+%3D+x*x%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09return+x*y%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

So I wonder what the best way would be if you hand-coded it and why (ILP, dependencies,...).

Comment: What is the type of `n`?

Comment: Please put all these details in your question.  Each Stack Overflow question should be self-contained, so do not rely on code samples hosted on external sites.  Normally, I do not even look at them.

Comment: Added the entire function.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Now let's find out why the compiler doesn't use a conditional move.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter here, but not that in C++03 and earlier, the `auto` keyword works like C, and `auto m = n%2` is always `int m` regardless of the type of `n`.  Only in C++11 and later will you get `unsigned m` inferred from the type of the right hand side.

Comment: Yeah both compilers default to C++14 now and I'm usually on 1z/2a or whatever the latest one is :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test/je` can macro-fuse into a single uop on mainstream Intel and AMD CPUs, so in branchy code you'd only be saving code-size and costing 1 cycle of branch-miss-detection latency by using the CF output of a shift instead of an earlier `test/je`.

(Unfortunately gcc is really dumb here and uses `test edx,edx` on the result of `and edx,1`, instead of just using `test dl,1` or better `test sil,1` to save the `mov` as well.  `test esi,1` would use the imm32 encoding, because there's no `test r/m32, imm8` encoding for `test`, so compilers know to read narrow registers for `test`.)

But in a branchless implementation like clang uses, yes you'd save a uop by using the CF output for `cmovc` instead of separately computing an input for `cmove` with `test`.  You still don't shorten the critical path because `test` and `shr` can run in parallel, and mainstream CPUs like Haswell or Ryzen have wide enough pipelines to fully exploit all the ILP and just bottleneck on the `imul` loop-carried dependency chain.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).

Actually it's the `cmov` -> `imul` -> next iteration dep chain for `y` that's the bottleneck.  On Haswell and earlier, `cmov` is 2 cycle latency (2 uops), so the total dep chain is 2+3 = 5 cycles.  (Pipelined multipliers mean that doing an extra `y*=1` multiply isn't slowing down the `x*=x` part or vice versa; they can both be in flight at once just not start in the same cycle.)

If you're using the same `n` repeatedly for different bases, a branchy version should predict well, and be very good because branch-prediction + speculative execution decouples data dependency chains.

Otherwise it's probably better to eat the longer latency of a branchless version instead of suffering branch misses.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for an answer like this. Could you explain what you mean by 'costing 1 cycle of branch-miss-detection latency'?

Comment: Interestingly gcc does use test sil,1 if you get rid of m (which was supposed to help the compiler): https://godbolt.org/z/9oL1oc